go gin close channel cause panic
I am using golang gin with mqtt3.1, build a device management app.
While I am using mqtt3.1 and need to build a synchronous mechanism, so I utilized go channel.
Here's my summary fake code:
var mqttChannels = make(map[string]chan []byte)

func NodeRequestSync(c *gin.Context, mqttPath string, deviceId string, payload interface{}, timeout time.Duration) (string, error) {
    requestId := uuid.New().String() 
    requestTopic := myRequestTopic(nodeId, mqttPath, requestId)
    //mqttChannels is a map of channel:   var mqttChannels = make(map[string]chan []byte)
    mqttChannels[requestId] = make(chan []byte)
    //send mqtt request
    NodeClient.Publish(requestTopic, 0, false, payload)
    //handle response
    select {
    case responseData := <-mqttChannels[requestId]:
        //recieved data, now close the channel with the requestId
        delete(mqttChannels, requestId)
                //return data to next manipulation
        return string(responseData), nil
    case <-time.After(timeout):
        //timeout, close the channel with the requestId,too.
        delete(mqttChannels, requestId)
        return "", errors.New("timeout or node un-exist")
    }
}

func HandleDeviceResponse(client mqtt.Client, msg mqtt.Message) {
        //i added the requestId at last of the response topic. for example:
        // requestTopic: req/test/<requestId>.   responseTopic: resp/test/<requestId>
    requestId := msg.Topic()[strings.LastIndex(msg.Topic(), "/")+1:]
    _, ok := mqttChannels[requestId]
    if ok {
        mqttChannels[requestId] <- msg.Payload()
    }
}

This works fine for most of the time. However, when I send mqtt request very fast(like refresh my browser by click my mouse very fast), then I will got a panic, it point directly at the delete(mqttChannels, requestId) line, it seems I am deleting a closing channel? But it seems make no sense cause I am using uuid for every request, i am sure that the requestId are unique when panic happens.
And I tried to add a delay before close the channel, it seems fixed the pannic, but I still don't know why and can not 100% sure bug is fixed.
Is there any one could help me figure where I did wrong? cause this is like a bomb that I am not sure if it will still boom after I delay some time there...
case responseData := <-mqttChannels[requestId]:
        time.Sleep(time.Millisecond * 100) // add this line seems to fix ?
        delete(mqttChannels, requestId)
        return string(responseData), nil


Maps in Go are not safe for concurrent reads/writes (see this question). I suspect that protecting the map operations with a Mutex will resolve the issue (if not please try to provide a reproducible example (and include the panic details in your question).

You have multiple race conditions in you code, run in with go run -race
The map mqttChannels is not thread safe, and deleting from the map doesn't close the channel.
Generally, it would be better to have one place (struct) where you (synchronously) submit requests and handle responses, instead of relying on global variables.
Also, when you time out in case <-time.After(timeout), HandleDeviceResponse hangs on a late answer since no-one is receiving the value anymore.
You could use a async.Promise and wait on the Future or use promise.Promise if you prefer channels.
